# How to show integers in a String through recursion

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I am new to Haskell and I am running into some problems with my recursive solution. I would appreciate any and all help!

My first goal was to create a function that would check the order of the string of "A", "B" and "C" and to output an integer array mapping each of these to a number via recursion.

My second goal was to create a function that would take two integer arrays (one of them would be the integer array created from `check_order` (consisting of 1, 2, and 3) and one would be a random integer array of length 3) and return a string such that 1 would be replaced by the first element of the random integer array, 2 would be replaced by the second element of the random integer array, etc.

Here is my code:

```
-- Takes any String consisting of namely A, B, and C and returns an Integer
-- with 1, 2, and 3 that corresponds to each particular character.
check_order :: String -> [Int]
check_order "" = []
check_order (x:xs)
    | x `elem` "A" = 1 : check_order xs
    | x `elem` "B" = 2 : check_order xs
    | otherwise    = 3 : check_order xs
    
-- Takes the integer array generated from check_order and an arbitrary
-- integer array of length 3 and returns a String correlating the check_order
-- array and the arbitrary integer array
number_correction :: Integral n => [n] -> [n] -> String
number_correction [] _ = ""
number_correction (x:xs) num_array
    | x == 1 = show (num_array !! 0) ++ " " ++ number_correction xs num_array
    | x == 2 = show (num_array !! 1) ++ " " ++ number_correction xs num_array
    | otherwise    = show (num_array !! 2) ++ " " ++ number_correction xs num_array
    
main = do
       let test = "ABCBABBAC";
       let num_array = [6, 1, 8];
       print(number_correction(check_order(test), num_array));
       
       --This print statement should print out "6 1 8 1 6 1 1 6 8"
```

Here are the error logs:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, main.o )
main.hs:12:16: error:• Could not deduce(Show n) arising from a use of ‘show’
      from the context: Integral n
        bound by the type signature for:number_correction :: Integral n => [n] -> [n] -> String
        at main.hs:9:1-55
      Possible fix:add (Show n) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            number_correction :: Integral n => [n] -> [n] -> String
    • In the firstargument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘show (num_array !! 0)’
      In the expression:
        show (num_array !! 0) ++ " " ++ number_correction xs num_array
      In anequation for ‘number_correction’:
          number_correction (x : xs) num_array
            | x == 1
            =show (num_array !! 0) ++ " " ++ number_correction xs num_array
            | x == 2
            = show (num_array !! 1) ++ " " ++ number_correction xs num_array
        | otherwise
            = show (num_array !! 2) ++ " " ++ number_correction xs num_array

main.hs:19:31: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[n0]’
        with actual type ‘([Int], [Integer])’
    • In the first argument of ‘number_correction’, namely
        ‘(check_order (test), num_array)’
      In the first argument of ‘print’, namely
        ‘(number_correction (check_order (test), num_array))’
      In a stmt of a'do' block:
        print (number_correction (check_order (test), num_array))
```

Comment: Have you tried writing `[Int] -> [Int]` instead of `(Int n) => [n] -> [n]`?

Comment: I have not. I have been trying to teach myself through learnyouahaskell.com's tutorial and I found them using the way that I have been traditionally using. I will try the newer way. What is the main difference?

Comment: Could you point to where you have found your usage in leanyouahaskell.com?

Comment: The main difference is that one (yours) uses type classes and the other one doesn't. I'm not very familiar with Haskell so I'm not sure if it even makes sense to use `Int` as a type class.

Comment: Of course @mkrieger1. http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions. The 'addVectors' and the 2nd 'tellBmi' function (the one with two parameters).

Comment: I've edited my post to incorporate leftaroundabout's advice.

Comment: Please don't edit questions in a way that makes existing answers obsolete. (Admittedly, my answer didn't really address the main part of the question in the first place, but it did address another problem with your code.)

Comment: At this point in your learning I would recommend avoiding all typeclasses (signatures with a fat `=>` arrow).  So just use `[Int] -> [Int] -> String`, and use concrete types like this everywhere in signatures.

Answer (score 1):

`(Int n) => [n] -> [n] -> String` doesn't make any sense. `Int` is a concrete type, so what is `Int n` supposed to mean? It's like writing

```
foo = True 37
```

– you're trying to use something as a function that's not a function.

What you probably had in mind is the admittedly very similar-looking

```
number_correction :: Integral n => [n] -> [n] -> String
```

Unlike `Int`, [`Integral`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integral) is a type *class*. Unlike in Java, types and classes in Haskell are completely different beasts. In particular, `Integral` *is* a function on the type level. You can see this in GHCi:

```
Prelude> :k Int
Int :: Type
Prelude> :k Integral
Integral :: Type -> Constraint
```

(traditionally it would show `*` and `* -> Constraint`, with `*` being the old symbol denoting the kind of types).

So, `Integral n` does make sense: you apply the `Type -> Constraint` to a variable `n` of kind `Type`, and thus get a constraint. Constraints are what can appear on the LHS of the `=>` arrow.

You *could* also make a constraint with `Int`. That requires the (common enough) `-XTypeFamilies` extension, then you can write

```
number_correction :: (n ~ Int) => [n] -> [n] -> String
```

In this case you basically use the “class of all types which are equal to `Int`”, which is a bit silly. The `Integral` class contains the type `Int`, but also other types such as `Integer` and [`Int32`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Int.html#t:Int32).

If you really want to allow only `Int`, you should simply write

```
number_correction :: [Int] -> [Int] -> String
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This helps me understand the difference between what I traditionally have used in an incorrect fashion (Int) vs this Integral type class. I appreciate it, @leftaroundabout.

Comment: Any idea on how to improve my recursive call on number_correction?